# Gmlib 1.5.3 Google Maps Script Error

Tags: gmlib

GMLib 1.5.3 stopped working today :( , maybe 3-4 hours ago . When I try to zoom out , or move something I receive an error .

Is there a solutions for this ? Or any hope that it will be fixed soon ? ( if one may ask :) )

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm working on that

Comment: thank you , do you accept donations ? :) I mean this component rocks

Comment: I havent changed anything , but ... it seems to be working now . Can anyone else confirm ? Did google break something , and then fixed it overnight ?

Comment: never mind, it worked temporarily... I wanted to demonstrate something right now same error... AAAA google :)

Comment: The solution into my blog here "http://www.cadetill.com/en/gmlib-and-this-page-didnt-load-google-maps-correctly-error/

Comment: and, of course, all donate are welcome here http://www.cadetill.com/gmlib_en/#helpmetohelpyou :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had errors since last week on GMLib 1.5.3.

I resolved thanks to these 3 actions :

1 : Download the last 1.5.3 version like Cadetill says to inject an Google Api Gmap key

2 : I received a 404 error on page https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmarker/src/StyledMarker.js  => In fact Google migrate it to https://cdn.rawgit.com/jacopotarantino/google-maps-utility-library-v3/master/styledmarker/src/StyledMarker.js  . Ok but where I could change this URL? It's on gmmapres.res files inside component directory. It's a ressource file, so you must edit with a resource editor. ANd change URL. ANd it work. On my solution, I integrated all content of this StyledMarked.js inside the file gmmapres.res. (Inside   node). This secure my solution on futur url modification.

3 : After corrected these 2 previous steps, My gmap component still not working. In fact it was caused by an endless loop. I corrected exactly like Telecetera explain on this post : [Endless Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44064461/gmmap-afterpageloaded-endless-loop)

And it's now working perfectly.

Hope this experience help some others persons.