# GMMap AfterPageLoaded Endless Loop

Tags: gmlib

I wrote an application using GMLIb a couple of years ago and it has been working up until yesterday.
I read the fix, got a key, recompiled the code with v1.5.4 and v1.5.5 and have the same result.

The code is caught in an endless loop at AfterPageLoaded

if First then
    FGMMap.DoMap;

First is never true.

Is anyone else experience this problem.
XE7 on Win7 64

20/05/2017 
Removed GMLib. Reinstalled.
Compiled and ran the Megademo and the result is the same. An endless loop at AfterPageLoaded.

Created a simple test program using GMMap component and the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same issue, but it seems that it is solved now!It happened at users who had IE 8 version on their machines - but I don't really know, why...

What is important though, is updating the IE to the latest version solves the problem!

Comment: I went to a lot of trouble removing IE from my ;puter some years ago! :)

Comment: I was very skeptical about this solution.
I had a bit of time and a backup plan and tried it.
Installed IE10 and upgrades.
Guess what?
It worked.
Thanks @Acheron

Comment: You're welcome ;) What is sad though, it is not a solution, just a workaround :(

Answer (score 0):

Not so much of an answer, but a very similar issue and - I think - a workaround.

Again, this only affects certain machines, most have IE10 installed. My issue is not that First is never true but that it is always true.

```
procedure TFMain.GMMapAfterPageLoaded(Sender: TObject; First: Boolean);
begin

    if (First) and (PLCount = 0) then    // was just if First then
    begin
        GMMap.DoMap;
        BShowInfo.Enabled := True;
    end;
    Inc(PLCount);
end;
```

Altering GMMapAfterPageLoaded as above (initialising PLCount to 0 first) seems to give the DoMap call enough time to work properly