# GmLib 1.5.5 loading issue (map isn't loading and application crashes)

Tags: delphi, gmlib

Since GmLib 1.5.5 the map isn't loading anymore and my application crashes. 
It only occurs under WinXP. Does anyone have an idea for this behavior?

Comment: This is a statement of fact, not a question. If you have a problem with a library, you should surely contact the developer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution for this problem, and you can read it here:
[GMMap AfterPageLoaded Endless Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44064461/gmmap-afterpageloaded-endless-loop)

I hope, it helps...

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the problem but I can't update the IE, because I'm using D7 under a WinXP VM and WinXP only supports IE till version 8. Could be there another solution?

Comment: Not that I know of...I also have some users who still have XP, and would not update, so for them I had to introduce an offline version of my application, that does not use this otherwise great component. So if you, or anyone finds another solution, it is more than welcome :)